# Make a Bootstrap jumbotron's width extend atleast upto the amount of content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that consist of a fixed navbar,fixed footer and in between them I have a bootstrap jumbotron.**The jumbotron's content has been divided into two columns as shown below(one with id="tasks" & other with id="view").When I resize the browser, as expected ,the two columns gets stacked one above the other.The problem is that since the left column consist of fewer content,after browser resize(and after left column gets stacked on top of the right column),the width of the jumbotron now is equal to the width of the left column**.As a result the right column is now not entirely inside the jumbotron
      **Below is code**

```
  <body>
   <div id="header">
      <?php echo $navbar; ?>
   </div>
   <div id="jumbotron" class="jumbotron row">
     <div  class="container-fluid">
        <div id="tasks" class="col-md-2">//the left column contains fewer contents
           <?php echo $task_set; ?>
        </div>
       <div id="view" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">//the right-column
           <?php echo $view_to_load ?>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div id="footer" class="row">
     <?php echo $footer; ?>
   </div>
 </body>
```

Please tell me how can i make the jumbotron's width equal to width of the right column i.e. the column with id=""view

Comment: if you want to remain same of all screen add class on col-xs what you need for ,change the class type for mobile tablet or what you are trying to

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement different classes for when your viewport is smaller.
So per example `<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12">` if you'd like it full size on a small viewport.